# How to make Visual Studio 2017 (PVTS) see my existing virtual envs created with conda?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, pvts

I installed Anaconda 4.3.1 along with Visual Studio 2017 preview.
Since I need Python 3.5 for Tensorflow I created a separate virtual environment using conda, targeting this version of Python.

The problem I have is I cannot make Visual Studio see the environments created with conda. "Add existing virtual env" doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to attach my environment to a project in PVTS?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085769/use-conda-environment-in-vs2017

Comment: @Herman, The issue is not solved, but I managed to make Python 3.5 coexist with 3.6. I installed VS without Anaconda, but kept Python 3.6, then I separately installed Anaconda 4.2 with Python 3.5. Like that, VS can see both root envs of Python 3.6 and 3.5 and allows me to switch between versions. I then installed TensorFlow in Anaconda 4.2 root env.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I've managed to fix it by creating a custom environment in VS. Like it is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40839135/1161635