# Use conda environment in VS2017

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, visual-studio-2017, pvts

I want to use a conda virtual environment with VS2017, but I get the error that it could not identify a virtual environment in the selected path. The screenshot below is not mine, but it's from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813236/add-cntk-virtualenv-to-visual-studio-python-project), which is similar but does not solve my problem. My path is `C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\tensorflow`.

[image: We could not identify a virtual environment in the selected path.]

I have installed python 3.6 and anaconda 4.3.0 using the Visual Studio 2017 installer. Then I've followed the steps on SO to [create a python 3.5 environment for tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053502/1161635).

My guess is that Visual Studio doesn't recognize the python 3.5 installation, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to solve that without making a mess of my system.

There is a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154187/how-to-make-visual-studio-2017-pvts-see-my-existing-virtual-envs-created-with), but it has no responses. Here is a gist of my [python diagnostic info](https://gist.github.com/HermanEldering/b3db74a843c4465dd56a954614ad5f7f) from VS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, it turns out that this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40839135/1161635) is correct after all. It works after creating a custom environment within Visual Studio.